# Provide backwards compatibility for Geometry type in Jooq 3.16

Tags: java, geometry, generator, compatibility, jooq

first of all, I love using Jooq since it helps me efficiently ship the things I want to do. But one thing bothers me since the release of 3.16 bringing some new features.

Also it would be great to adopt semantic versioning so users can know when to expect something to break.

In second, 3.16 version brings `org.jooq.impl.Geometry` class which gets generated by default even if I use custom configuration (Converter to convert from byte array to jts) from previous version which did the job perfectly, see this config:

```
<forcedType>
   <types>(geometry|GEOMETRY)</types>
   <userType>com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry</userType>
   <converter>com.example.GeometryConverter</converter> <!-- converts Object to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry -->
</forcedType>
```

In 3.15 generator generates the following code

```
createField(DSL.name("geopoint"), org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("\"myDb\".\"geopoint\"").nullable(false), this, "", new GeometryConverter());
```

and in 3.16:

```
createField(DSL.name("geopoint"), SQLDataType.GEOMETRY.nullable(false), this, "")
```

this leaves me with mentioned `org.jooq.impl.Geometry` class which I don't find useful (specially because it contains String - instead of more useful bytes (containing WKB or WKT data) and does not bring any added value (in terms of handling geography)).

As far as I can understand from the log
`The out of the box binding for geometry is available in the commercial jOOQ distribution only. Alternatively, you can implement your own custom binding.` Jooq forced me to write my custom GeometryBinding class which will handle all I didn't need in the first place and worked in 3.15.

Is there a way to workaround this using configuration because [release notes](https://www.jooq.org/notes) does not mention anything regarding this change or migration guide.

Jooq helps me save a lot of time during development but can take a lot of time when it is time to upgrade since I like to be kind of early adopter bringing (at least a) feedback back to the community so we can do great things!

PS: Jakarta upgrade is another problem since Jooq is always on top of some framework which may not support Jakarta validation 3.x yet leaving us (early adopters) with compilation issues, but this is a common problem. I will suggest to add an option to the generator which turns off validation code since is not needed in many cases.

Comment: *"I will suggest to add an option to the generator which turns off validation code since is not needed in many cases."* - It's not generated by default, you must have turned it on yourself...

Comment: You are right. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

#### Turning off spatial data type support

Starting from jOOQ 3.17.0 and 3.16.5, you can turn off spatial data type support in jOOQ's code generator, in order to rever to the jOOQ 3.15 behaviour of generating a `SQLDataType.OTHER` type reference. For this, specify:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <generate>
      <spatialTypes>false</spatialTypes>
    </generate>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

[This new code generation feature is documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-extended-types/)

#### Your specific questions

> Also it would be great to adopt semantic versioning so users can know when to expect something to break.

The official stance on backwards compatibility is here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/semantic-versioning/

There's an explicit section about code generation. One caveat is when we introduce new data types, in case of which existing converters / bindings (that assumed `Object`) stop working and need a migration. This has happened before for `XML`, `JSON` types, and now for `GEOMETRY`. I can't think of a reasonable way to prevent that, but the migration isn't too hard either.

> In 3.15 generator generates the following code [...]

The fact that your converter is no longer added to the generated code looks like a bug to me. Feel free to report it with some additional details, including your `CREATE TABLE` statement: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

> this leaves me with mentioned org.jooq.impl.Geometry class which I don't find useful (specially because it contains String - instead of more useful bytes (containing WKB or WKT data) and does not bring any added value (in terms of handling geography)).

The Spatial support project is vast, and it is far from complete. There were two options:

1. Wait forever for the next release, which includes a more complete integration
2. Ship an MVP which already adds quite a bit of value to those who wish to standardise over spatial extensions of different dialects.

Some issues to keep an eye out for:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12736
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12738 (this will restore the JTS bindings for you)

> As far as I can understand from the log The out of the box binding for geometry is available in the commercial jOOQ distribution only. Alternatively, you can implement your own custom binding. Jooq forced me to write my custom GeometryBinding class which will handle all I didn't need in the first place and worked in 3.15.

I know this is the caveat when we introduce support for new types. But unfortunately, I don't see another solution for this. But is writing this binding really that much work? It should take 10 minutes...

> Jooq helps me save a lot of time during development but can take a lot of time when it is time to upgrade since I like to be kind of early adopter bringing (at least a) feedback back to the community so we can do great things!

Is this really the case every time, or did you just get unlucky with this particular binding thing?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Sorry for being hard on this, din't mean in this way. It is rare that I have issues with upgrades. Common problems are API incompatibility which can be in many cases quickly resolved. I don't change the generator and configuration logic often but sometimes (like this) some things may not be trivial to change since it requires to get through documentation again... Great work about spacial support I hope I can leave my mark someday as well.

Comment: @Gregor: I can relate. You have other things to do, and the upgrade now feels more like a chore than a benefit. It *is* a service release after all, without game changing features yet (the new query object model is a game changer, but that, too, is only available in a very experimental state). So, if 2-3 hurdles pile up, that's definitely frustrating. All of these things are tradeoffs for maintenance, too. E.g. should Jakarta EE and Java EE be supported in parallel? I think not, because our integration isn't strategic. But the incompatibility causes cognitive friction...

Comment: @Gregor: Another really annoying upgrade was the H2 dependency (in case you were using the `DDLDatabase`), which also changed quite incompatibly between 1.4 and 2.0. Due to numerous CVE's jOOQ was forced to upgrade... Anyway, the next release will be much less controversial again. I'll think a bit more about the converter issue. Perhaps, there *is* a possibility to gracefully upgrade and opt out of the out-of-the-box jOOQ type support, also for `JSON` and `XML`...

Comment: @Gregor: I'd love to learn more about the API incompatibilities you've mentioned. That shouldn't happen. The integration tests cover a lot of usages to prevent this, but perhaps you ran into oversights? What did you have in mind, specifically, if you remember?

Comment: I agree. I am writing micro services using my library (which is on top of Jooq) and those services are using different frameworks (Quarkus, KumuluzEE,...) and every frameworks has different bag of dependencies and versions.  Quarkus actually postponed moving to jakarta package due to the reasons in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21574 therefore I got problems with Jooq but luckily I don't use validation on ORM level.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the pointer. Good to know. It's much harder for Quarkus to upgrade as they have a tighter integration with the EE packages. For jOOQ it was simple. And more urgent. This issue here helped expedite the task: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28821

Comment: Yes, H2 is another problem I lost a lot of time since upgrade was needed due to the vulnerabilities which were fixed only in 2.x branch and not in 1.4. After upgrading to new versions (jooq, liquibase,...) the issue disappeared, not sure if was fixed by Jooq or Liquibase. All good now.

Comment: APIs are all good, with incompatibility I meant generator which was previously generating different DataType. I will try to fix it with custom Binding, but please, change Geometry data from String to byte[] in 3.17 because JTS returns byte array and conversion to string and back is painful since Strings depend on character sets.

Comment: @Gregor: You know the drill for that `String` vs `byte[]` feature request :) https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose